# Как вставить фото в БД через json?

Tags: php, json, photo

Есть форма ("Добавить модель авто").
В нее я пишу к примеру: Модель: Гелентваген, Описание: Классный джип. И гружу фото. Отправляю через POST в "process.php" в БД (денвер, php 5.2.12).
В нем:

```
$json=normJsonStr(json_encode($_POST)); // где, normJsonStr - это функция для   отображения кириллицы.
$sql = "INSERT INTO car_models (model_name, photo,  opisanie, marka_id, json)values('$mod_name','$file_name','$opisanie', $marka_id, '$json')";
```

В БД, в поле json вставляется:

`{"target":"add_model","model_name":"Гелентваген","opisanie":"Классный джип","marka_id":"11"}`

а фото внутрь не вставляется!

Хотя в обычном поле "photo" фото Гелентвагена есть!

Как сделать так, чтобы и в json'e оно отображалось?

**Обновление**

В спешке, совсем забыл! Извиняюсь!

Фото приходит в БД через `$_FILES`.

```
$mod_name=@$_POST['model_name'];
$opisanie=@$_POST['opisanie'];
$marka_id=@$_POST['marka_id'];
$json=normJsonStr(json_encode($_POST));

$file_name=null;
$file_error=@$_FILES['photo_file']['error'];
if($file_error==0){
    $file_name=@$_FILES['photo_file']['name'];
    $file_tmp_name=@$_FILES['photo_file']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"../uploads/$file_name");
}
```

Где на выходе у него получается `$file_name` - который и вставляется в INSERT. Поэтому его и не цепляло. Сейчас пробую их объединить - не получается.

Может у Вас есть мысли?!

Comment: В [JSON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) фото никак не будет отображаться. Это текстовый формат обмена данными. В поле 'photo' у Вас хранится ссылка на файл. Но, в JSON у Вас этой ссылки почему-то нет. Только описание автомобиля.

Comment: И ещё. Лучше откажитесь от использования Denwer'a. Это платформа ужасного качества. Кроме того он уже давно толком не развивается (последнее изменение на оф.сайте датируется 2 июня 2013 года).

Comment: 1) Да там хранится имя - "2.jpg"; Именно это имя мне и надо.

Comment: 2) Спасибо за совет! Думаю скоро перейти на ОпенСервер!

Answer (score 2):

1. Используйте multipart/form-data (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data)
2. Воспользуйтесь гайдом по передаче файлов на сервер:

a) http://javascript.ru/blog/gordon-freeman/AJAX-otpravka-fajla-Kak-otpravit-fajl-s-pomoshu-Ajax-Kak-otpravit-fajl-javascrip
б) https://wpcafe.org/hacks/ajax-zagruzka-faylov-na-server-s-pomoshhyu-jquery/

Мне нравится работа с jQuery (ниже - текст с сайта):

```
// Переменная куда будут располагаться данные файлов

var files;

// Вешаем функцию на событие
// Получим данные файлов и добавим их в переменную

$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    files = this.files;
});
```

Это обработчик поля формы, принимающего файл для загрузки.

А далее - передача файла в обрабатывающий скрипт:

```
// Вешаем функцию ан событие click и отправляем AJAX запрос с данными файлов

$('.submit.button').click(function( event ){
    event.stopPropagation(); // Остановка происходящего
    event.preventDefault();  // Полная остановка происходящего

    // Создадим данные формы и добавим в них данные файлов из files

    var data = new FormData();
    $.each( files, function( key, value ){
        data.append( key, value );
    });

    // Отправляем запрос

    $.ajax({
        url: './submit.php?uploadfiles',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, // Не обрабатываем файлы (Don't process the files)
        contentType: false, // Так jQuery скажет серверу что это строковой запрос
        success: function( respond, textStatus, jqXHR ){

            // Если все ОК

            if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){
                // Файлы успешно загружены, делаем что нибудь здесь

                // выведем пути к загруженным файлам в блок '.ajax-respond'

                var files_path = respond.files;
                var html = '';
                $.each( files_path, function( key, val ){ html += val +'<br>'; } )
                $('.ajax-respond').html( html );
            }
            else{
                console.log('ОШИБКИ ОТВЕТА сервера: ' + respond.error );
            }
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log('ОШИБКИ AJAX запроса: ' + textStatus );
        }
    });

});
```

Далее - вариации на тему json_encode - т.е. на стороне сервера обнаруживаем ключ для файла и производим его десериалитзацию или запись в базу, как BLOB.

Вывод - в обратном направлении - из BLOB в сериализованный вид и - на выдачу.

**Но предупреждаю - это не путь джедая! Лучше просто складывайте картинки на контент-сервер или просто на диск! Не убивайте производительность своей БД!**

Answer (score 1):

Получился такой ответ. Надеюсь он пригодится моим коллегам! :-)

1) Из формы "index.php" отправляем данные в "process.php".

```
<?php<br>

if($target=="add_model"){<br>

    $mod_name=@$_POST['model_name']; // пришло название модели <br>
    $opisanie=@$_POST['opisanie'];  // ее описание<br>
    $marka_id=@$_POST['marka_id'];  // id марки<br> 

    $file_name=null;                               // фото модели<br>
    $file_error=@$_FILES['photo_file']['error'];<br>
    if($file_error==0){<br>
        $file_name=@$_FILES['photo_file']['name'];<br>
        $file_tmp_name=@$_FILES['photo_file']['tmp_name'];<br>
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"../uploads/$file_name");<br>
    }

    $far=array('model_name'=>$mod_name, 'opisanie'=>$opisanie, 'marka_id'=>$marka_id, 'photo'=>$file_name); <br>
    // создаем массив из поступивших данных<br>

    $json=normJsonStr(json_encode($far)); // обработка json <br>

    // В итоге в БД, в поле "json" получаем <br>
    // {"model_name":"C-Class Coupe","opisanie":"Купе класса G1.","marka_id":"11","photo":"5.jpg"}<br>

    $sql="SELECT * FROM car_models WHERE model_name='$mod_name'";<br>

    $res=mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));<br>
    $get=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);<br>

    if($get['id']==0){      <br>
    $sql = "INSERT INTO car_models (model_name, photo, opisanie, marka_id, json)values('$mod_name','$file_name','$opisanie', $marka_id, '$json')";<br>
    $res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);<br>
        echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";<br>
    }   <br>
}<br>
?><br>
```